# How can the effects of a Gene become weaker with each new offspring?

Tags: biology, genetics

King Solomon, founder of the Solomonian Dynasty, was the first emperor of China. After he conquered the mainland, he gave his alchemists the single command of creating an elixir that would allow him to live forever. This elixir not only made him immortal, but unlocked an ability in his genes that gave him access to eye abilities. This power was called the sharringan, and made him the most powerful being in China.

Being immortal allowed him to secure his empire for millennia. To this end, he secured 900 wives and 600 concubines to propagate his legacy, and led him to produce tens of thousands of children. These individuals are not immortal, but do possess the sharringan eye. This allowed him to build a conquering army of his own offspring.

However, there is a problem. It was discovered that the sharringan became weaker with every child produced. While the first few kids of the emperor maintained full powers of the eye, those abilities decreased in every new child being born. Proceeding generations will gain weaker abilities until it is barely existent at all.

Why would the abilities of this gene deteriorate with each new individual born?

Comment: Are you sure than *sharringan* is a possible word in Classical Chinese? With that double *r*? (And, of course, the only imaginable pronunciation would be something like shar--ring--un, wouldn't it? Sinitic languages have very different phonotactics than Japanese...) Honest questions.

Comment: I think the Naruto eye to use would be "rinnegan", the meaning fits your idea and since it uses real words you could translate it to Chinese. Or better yet English.

Comment: diluted by the wife and concubine gene? unless this is the sweet home alabama kind

Comment: @AlexP The Kanji for that in Naruto is 写轮眼 (the middle word should not be simplified chinese, but could not copy paste it in properly)， pronounced like shie lun yan. It would mean Writing Wheel Eyes literally if in chinese, or copy wheel eyes in Japanese (the two meanings are different due to, although the word being the same, meanings between terms being used differently in Japanese vs Chinese), as is used in Naruto.

Comment: Is this by generation or my individual offspring? You're not entirely clear about which applies.

Comment: becasue it is not one gene but many genes, so unless his offspring are inbreeding some of the genes are lost due to recombination with each generation. the trick is it will not be the same genes lost in each individual so the abilities should vary wildly, of course one enough generation go by the genes can get recombined since people will not see themselves are related.

Answer (score 1):

There is a kind of DNA consisting of many trinucleotide repeats. This DNA will 'slip' while replicating, so the number of repeats will vary from generation to generation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinucleotide_repeat_disorder  symptoms or onset of these changes become more severe with each passing generation (I'm taking liberties with the description for simplicity) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticipation_(genetics) If the trait requires a certain number of repeats, but the number keeps going up, the gene (ability) will gradually be disrupted and cease to function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- With each second the potion influence on Solomon weaken in the way that it's influence over his testicles lessen. His body is changed forever but sperm, as is constantly produced new "batch" is trying to return to homeostasis it knew, before the change.
- The women are changing. With each second of Solomon eistence his mere presence make world change. It cannot change him, due to nature of potion, but it can change the outcome. So with each new women born their genes are more and more dominant over Solomon ones. Let's say the *sharringan* gene power is dominant after drinking the potion. Nature cannot make it recessive in Solomon himself but can in relation to other one "supplied" by women. Nature don't need to hurry as Solomon is immortal so the change is slow and gradual.

Answer (score 0):

## Polygeny

The sharringan is [**polygenetic**](https://www.biologyonline.com/dictionary/polygene).

Whatever the elixir did, it gave Solomon multiple copies of the sharringan gene, and each gene has been inserted in both chromosomes of each pair where they appear. Each copy strengthens the trait.

When Solomon reproduces, he only passes on half of those genes. His progeny, due to [genetic recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination), and due sharringan not being positively selected through either natural or artificial means, will have less and less copies of the gene on each generation - except when inbreeding is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Very few genetic traits are the result of a single gene. Usually a number of different genes contribute to producing and moderating traits. Each generation of offspring that inherits this gene will also inherit genes from their mothers, and so the unique combination of genes that gave Solomon his nifty powers is watered down by random alterations in each subsequent generation.